# What is the syntax of searchQuery in android calendar instanceQuery method?

Tags: android, android-calendar

Can anyone please provide an example for a search query in android calendar instance.

I wanted to query the instances table with start time, end time and event_id.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check here? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#instances

Comment: yeah, I checked the document there is no syntax. they only given space separated string.       https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html#query(android.content.ContentResolver, java.lang.String[], long, long, java.lang.String)

Comment: I see your point. My guess is it searches for multiple keywords in the event? The trouble is knowing where it searches and how to add boolean operators... I guess you can only experiment your way out of this one. :/